# Application Yml Map<String,Map<String,List<Object>>> in spring boot structure

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, yaml

I have a collection

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="com.ptsb.refData")
public class RefDataConfigMap {

    private Map<String,Map<String,List<RefDataResponse>>> entries;

    public Map<String, Map<String, List<RefDataResponse>>> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }

    public void setEntries(Map<String, Map<String, List<RefDataResponse>>> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }
```

RefDataRespone:

```
public class RefDataResponse {

      @JsonProperty("sourceSystem")
      private String refKeyTgtSystem = null;

      @JsonProperty("sourceSystemValue")
      private String refKeyTgtSystemValue = null;

    public String getRefKeyTgtSystem() {
        return refKeyTgtSystem;
    }

    public void setRefKeyTgtSystem(String refKeyTgtSystem) {
        this.refKeyTgtSystem = refKeyTgtSystem;
    }

    public String getRefKeyTgtSystemValue() {
        return refKeyTgtSystemValue;
    }

    public void setRefKeyTgtSystemValue(String refKeyTgtSystemValue) {
        this.refKeyTgtSystemValue = refKeyTgtSystemValue;
    }

}
```

I am intializing in application.yml as show below

```
com:
  ptsb:
    refData:
      entries:
             GENDER:
                    Male:
                         - refKeyTgtSystem:Siebel
                           refKeyTgtSystemValue:M
```

I am getting an error when i trying to execute an application.

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.ptsb.ref.models.RefDataResponse' for property 'entries[GENDER][Male][0]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.ptsb.ref.models.RefDataResponse' for property 'entries[GENDER][Male][0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

How to initialize this in application yml?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
- refKeyTgtSystem:Siebel
  refKeyTgtSystemValue:M
```

defines a sequence with a single string entry, `"refKeyTgtSystem:Siebel refKeyTgtSystemValue:M"`. When in doubt, you can use online tools [using PyYAML](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/), [NimYAML](https://nimyaml.org/testing.html) (my work) or others to see how your YAML is being parsed.

The problem is that you forgot to add a space after the `:` characters. This is required by YAML for unquoted mapping keys. Even then, you used `@JsonProperty` to change the name of the keys, so the proper syntax is:

```
- sourceSystem: Siebel
  sourceSystemValue: M
```

Comment: It is working with refKeyTgtSystem and value only but as you said i should have added a space after : character.Now it is working ,Thanks!!!

Comment: Ah, could be because `@JsonProperty` is a Jackson thing but you're using Spring Boot.